# BuddyPress Edit activity function good practice

Tags: functions, customization, updates, buddypress, wp-update-post

I am using a custom BuddyPress edit function. However, I was told this is a bad practice and that I should use WordPress's helper function. How to correctly do this?
Here, is the code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_contest_entry', 'update_contest_entry');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_contest_entry', 'update_contest_entry');

function update_contest_entry() {
  global $wpdb;
    $entry_id = isset($_POST['entry_id']) ? intval($_POST['entry_id']) : 0;
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']) : '';
    $content = isset($_POST['body']) ? wp_kses_post($_POST['body']) : '';
    $signature = isset($_POST['signature']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['signature']) : '' ;
    $contentType = isset($_POST['contentType']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['contentType']) : '';

  if($contentType !== 'activity_comment'){
    $updated_activity = $wpdb->update(
      $wpdb->base_prefix . 'bp_activity',
      array(
          'content' => $content
      ),
      array('id' => $entry_id),
      array('%s'),
      array('%d')
    );
         $updated_meta = $wpdb->update(
          $wpdb->base_prefix . 'bp_activity_meta',
          array('meta_value' => $title),
          array('activity_id' => $entry_id, 'meta_key' => 'title'),
          array('%s'),
          array('%d', '%s')
      );

      $updated_meta_signature = $wpdb->update(
          $wpdb->base_prefix . 'bp_activity_meta',
          array('meta_value' => $signature),
          array('activity_id' => $entry_id, 'meta_key' => 'signature'),
          array('%s'),
          array('%d', '%s')
      );

      if ($updated_activity !== false && $updated_meta !== false && $updated_meta_signature !== false)  {
        wp_send_json_success('Contest entry updated successfully.');
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Error updating contest entry.');
    }
  }
  }
```

The feedback was that directly modifying the database is a bad practice. Use helper functions to update posts/meta in WordPress. But I didn't find any Buddypress/WordPress function to update activities.

Comment: have you looked at https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_activity_add/ and the other BP functions? `bp_activity_add`'s first documented parameter is an ID for an existing activity to update it

Comment: I actually want to edit the posts like (activity_update, activity_comment) from the activity stream page.

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference to my comment, did you check the source code of the BP Activity folder?

Comment: Oh ok, got it. So, by passing the id of the existing post. I can use bp_activity_add() to update the posts. It's great.

Comment: I left an answer, btw if you're relying on JSON for your AJAX you might want to consider using a REST API endpoint, that way you only need to return data and WP will JSON encode it for you, as well as giving you a pretty URL. Buddypress might already have endpoints you can interact with from JS that would let you bypass this entirely

Comment: Sure, thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/bp-activity/bp-activity-functions.php there's several functions:

### Activity Meta

I found `bp_activity_add_meta`, `bp_activity_delete_meta` and `bp_activity_update_meta` in that file, e.g. `bp_activity_update_meta`:

```php
        // Update activity meta counts.
        if ( bp_activity_update_meta( $activity_id, 'favorite_count', $fav_count ) ) {
```

### Activities

It looks like these can be updated the same way `wp_insert_post` can be used to update a post, by calling `bp_activity_add` with the updated information, and giving it an ID of the activity you want it to update

### Activity Comments

That file also includes all comment related functions, but it looks like `bp_activity_new_comment` works the same way as `wp_insert_post` in that you can modify a comment by passing its ID